# Difference between if and when statements in SQL

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case-when

If I have a table with a `number` column and want to create a new column with values of either 'high', 'medium' or 'low' based on the value in the number column can I use an if/else statement to do this? If so how would this be written?

I have this code for creating the column using a when/then statement:

```
use master

select 
    *, 
    case
       when (number > 40) then 'high'
       when (number between 30 and 40) then 'medium'
       else 'low'
    end as 'newColumn'
from 
    myTable
```

Basically I'm trying to understand the difference between if/else and when/then statements and why one would be used over the other.

This if/else code doesn't work but I don't know if it's because I'm coding it incorrectly:

```
use master

select 
    *,
    if (number > 40)
      'high'
    else if (number between 30 and 40)
      'medium'
    else 'low'
from 
    test
```

Comment: `IF` is a statement; `CASE` is an expression. You can't use statements in the middle of a `SELECT` statement (`IIF` is another expression that comes closer to a binary `IF`/`ELSE`, but is not an appropriate replacement for `CASE` here), nor can you use an expression where a statement is needed. They serve different use cases. To use an `IF` here, you'd have to write a statement with three different `SELECT`s (`IF number > 40 SELECT 'high' ELSE ...`) Whether one is better than the other in terms of performance/maintainability depends on the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF statement controls the flow and decides what has to be evaluated next, based on the condition, while CASE is a function which returns the desired value.

The CASE statement is more readable than IF statement when you compare a single expression against a range of unique values and more efficient as well.

Comment: In T-SQL, `CASE` is an expression rather than a statement as it is in other languages as @JeroenMostert mentioned in his comment. As an expression, `CASE` can conditionally return different values but does not conditionally execute statements.